# Firefox 46 configure: Python virtualenv regression (with bisect patch)

Tags: python, firefox, build, virtualenv, configure

When I try to configure Firefox 46 on Linux, I get the following error:

```
0:03.58 checking for python2.7... /usr/local/bin/python2.7
0:03.58 Creating Python environment
0:03.63 checking Python environment is Mozilla virtualenv... Traceback (most recent call last):
0:03.63   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
0:03.63 ImportError: No module named mozbuild.base
0:03.63 configure: error: Python environment does not appear to be sane.
0:03.63 ------ config.log ------
0:03.63 This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
0:03.63 running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.
0:03.63 
0:03.63 configure:1208: checking host system type
0:03.63 configure:1229: checking target system type
0:03.63 configure:1247: checking build system type
0:03.63 configure:1327: checking for mawk
0:03.63 configure:1327: checking for gawk
0:03.63 configure:1412: checking for python2.7
0:03.63 configure:1522: checking Python environment is Mozilla virtualenv
0:03.63 configure: error: Python environment does not appear to be sane.
0:03.63 *** Fix above errors and then restart with\
0:03.64                "/usr/local/bin/make -f client.mk build"
0:03.64 client.mk:359: recipe for target 'configure' failed
0:03.64 make: *** [configure] Error 1
```

I filled the following bug where I did a bisect identifying the patch causing this issue:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268251

The patch is the following:

```
The first bad revision is:
changeset:   317858:f7a8480e3efa
user:        Mike Hommey <mh+mozilla@glandium.org>
date:        Wed Jan 20 11:07:58 2016 +0900
summary:     Bug 1240990 - Define all backends in one place. r=gps
```

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/f7a8480e3efa

I contacted the author of the patch, but he didn't find a solution.

Since I can always configure, compile and install Firefox 45 and below, but not 46 (because of this patch), what is happening here? Maybe a virtualenv issue?

Thanks!

Ps: my Python installation is fine. I never had this kind of problem until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was caused by a symlink. It seems the Firefox build system doesn't deal with symlinks in this case. The solution is to change the path of ~/.mozconfig to the real location (instead of the symlink). You can see more details here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1268251